# Loop through JSON array shell script

Tags: json, macos, shell

I am trying to write a shell script that loops through a JSON file and does some logic based on every object's properties. The script was initially written for Windows but it does not work properly on a MacOS.

The initial code is as follows

```
    documentsJson=""        
    jsonStrings=$(cat "$file" | jq -c '.[]')

    while IFS= read -r document; do

        # Get the properties from the docment (json string)
        currentKey=$(echo "$document" | jq -r '.Key')
        encrypted=$(echo "$document" | jq -r '.IsEncrypted')

        # If not encrypted then don't do anything with it
        if [[ $encrypted != true  ]]; then
            echoComment " Skipping '$currentKey' as it's not marked for encryption"
            documentsJson+="$document,"

            continue
        fi
//some more code

   done <<< $jsonStrings
```

When ran on a MacOs, the whole file is processed at once, so it does not loop through objects. 
The closest I got to making it work - after trying a lot of suggestions - is as follows:

```
jq -r '.[]' "$file" | while read i; do

    for config in $i ; do

    currentKey=$(echo "$config" | jq -r '.Key')
    echo "$currentKey"

    done

done
```

The console result is `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6`

I just cannot find a proper way of grabbing the JSON object and reading its properties.

JSON file example

```
[
{
        "Key": "PdfMargins",
        "Value": {
            "Left":0,
            "Right":0,
            "Top":20,
            "Bottom":15
            }
        },
        {
        "Key": "configUrl",
        "Value": "someUrl",
        "IsEncrypted": true
    }
]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try putting the `$jsonStrings` in doublequotes: `done <<< "$jsonStrings"`.

Comment: Damn, that fixed it. I cannot mark your comment as the accepted answer tho.

Comment: I gave it as an answer to help you get closure on this question ;-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, the quotes shouldn't be necessary. They work around bugs that exist prior to `bash` 4.4 (4.3 fixed some, but not all, of them).

Comment: I wonder how necessary the shell processing is; `jq` can do a lot more than you might think. For example, you can extract the encrypted elements of the list with just `jq 'map(select(.IsEncrypted))` "$file"`.

Comment: @chepner Not that necessary but my skills are not that advanced yet. Just trying to make it work on a mac based on the windows version :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `$jsonStrings` in doublequotes: `done <<< "$jsonStrings"`

Otherwise the standard shell splitting applies on the variable expansion and you probably want to retain the line structure of the output of `jq`.

You could also use this in `bash`:

```
while IFS= read -r document; do
   ...
done < <(jq -c '.[]' < "$file")
```

That would save some resources.  I am not sure about making this work on MacOS, though, so test this first.